# Developer script exception - Invalid type: Component.Apex.Page

Tags: managed-package, exception

I've been receiving quite a lot of these recently as emails from a client org. This is the content of the email that I get

> Developer script exception from "*client organization name*" : "*my
>   apex trigger name*" : execution of AfterUpdate caused by: line 30,
>   column 39: Invalid type: Component.Apex.Page

The trigger is written on the ContentDocument object and in the trigger's after update method one of our custom object's record is inserted and nothing else.

Can anyone help me understand the cause for this exception and whether or not this is something I need to worry about?
Thanks in advance,
Gaurav

Comment: can you share your code...specially line no 30 ..

Comment: can you show us at line no 30 what code was written? if you could share complete code that will be really helpful

Comment: Transactions that generate exceptions are rolled back so each time this happens some change that should happen may not be happening. So yes track it down and fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't share the code. Line no. 30 calls a utility class method in which the Id of the record from Trigger.New is passed and a record for one of our custom objects is created using that Id. I hope this helps!!

Comment: I received this same error today - my guess is line 30 in the code is not our own code.  Seems pretty odd that we'd have the same line number and column in the error.  Line 30 in my code is just a string assignment.

tts.ContentVersionTriggers: execution of BeforeUpdate
caused by: line 30, column 39: Invalid type: Component.Apex.Page